# priority-web-sdk: Implementing a DATE8 field

Tags: javascript, date, erp

I'm trying to implement a Date type field. I'm splitting the data into 3 select fields for day, month and year, like so:

```
    <div id="CREATEDDATE" class="item" >
        <label>Date Opened</label>
        <select 
            id="CREATEDDATEdd" 
            class="dd" 
            date="CREATEDDATE" 
            onfocus="focusdiv(event)" 
            onblur="defocusdiv(event)"
        ></select>
        <select 
            id="CREATEDDATEmm" 
            class="mm" 
            date="CREATEDDATE" 
            onfocus="focusdiv(event)" 
            onblur="defocusdiv(event)"
        ></select>
        <select 
            id="CREATEDDATEyy" 
            class="yy" 
            date="CREATEDDATE" 
            onfocus="focusdiv(event)" 
            onblur="defocusdiv(event)"
        ></select>
    </div>
```

In the `updateFields` function I'm testing the `nodeName` of the element to decide what to do with the data. If the element is a `DIV` I handle it with a call to the `drawDate` function, passing in the parameters of the element and the value from the ROW to populate the select fields.

```
    function updateFields(result) {
        if (result[myForm.name]) {
            var fields = result[myForm.name][1];
            for (var fieldName in fields) {
                var el = document.getElementById(fieldName);
                if (el) {
                    switch (el.nodeName){                       
                        case "INPUT":
                            el.value = fields[fieldName];
                            break;

                        case 'SELECT':                  
                            fill(el, fields[fieldName]);
                            el.value = fields[fieldName];
                            break;

                        case "DIV":
                            drawDate(el, fields[fieldName]);
                            break;
                    };
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

The `fieldChangeHandler` checks to see if the calling `<select>` element contains the custom `date` attribute, which identifies the date field we are updating.

If it does, we create a Date object using the values set in the dd, mm, yy `<select>` elements and run the `fieldUpdate` function, like so:

```
    function fieldChangeHandler(event) {
        switch (event.srcElement.nodeName){                     
            case "INPUT":
                myForm.fieldUpdate(event.srcElement.id, event.target.value);
                break;

            case 'SELECT':
                if(event.srcElement.attributes["date"]){
                    var dt = new Date(0);
                    dt.setFullYear(
                        $('#'+event.srcElement.attributes["date"].nodeValue+'yy')[0].value,
                        $('#'+event.srcElement.attributes["date"].nodeValue+'mm')[0].value,
                        $('#'+event.srcElement.attributes["date"].nodeValue+'dd')[0].value
                    );
                    myForm.fieldUpdate(event.srcElement.attributes["date"].nodeValue, dt);

                } else {
                    myForm.fieldUpdate(event.srcElement.id, event.target.value);

                }
                break;                  
        };
    }
```

Lastly, I have the `drawDate` function which populates the `<option>`s on the first call from `updateFields`. Subsequent calls from `updateFields` set the `<selected>` attribute on the appropriate `<option>`, to keep the control synchronised with the data in the form column:

```
    function drawDate(el,sel){

        var i, dt = new Date(sel);
        var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
          "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
        ];

        var dd = ($('#'+el.id+'dd')[0].options.length==0);          
        for (i=1; i<32;i++) {
            if (i == dt.getDate()){
                if(dd){
                    $("#"+el.id+"dd").append('<option selected value="'+ i +'">'+ i +'</option>');
                }else{
                    $('#'+el.id+'dd')[0].options[(i-1)].selected = true;
                }

            } else {
                if(dd){
                    $('#'+el.id+"dd").append('<option value="'+ i +'">'+ i +'</option>')
                }else{
                    $('#'+el.id+'dd')[0].options[(i-1)].selected = false;
                };                  
            };
        };

        var mm = ($('#'+el.id+'mm')[0].options.length==0);          
        for (i=0; i<12;i++) {
            if (i == dt.getMonth()){
                if(mm){
                    $("#"+el.id+"mm").append('<option selected value="'+ i +'">'+ monthNames[i] +'</option>');
                }else{
                    $('#'+el.id+'mm')[0].options[(i)].selected = true;
                };

            } else {
                if(mm){
                    $('#'+el.id+"mm").append('<option value="'+ i +'">'+ monthNames[i] +'</option>');                                           
                }else{
                    $('#'+el.id+'mm')[0].options[(i)].selected = false;
                };
            };
        };

        var currentTime = new Date();
        var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
        var yy = ($('#'+el.id+'yy')[0].options.length==0);  
        var ind = 0;
        for (i=(year + 1); i>(year - 3);i--) {
            if (i == dt.getUTCFullYear()){
                if(yy){
                    $("#"+el.id+"yy").append('<option selected value="'+ i +'">'+ i +'</option>');
                }else{
                    $('#'+el.id+'yy')[0].options[ind].selected = true;
                };

            } else {
                if(yy){
                    $('#'+el.id+"yy").append('<option value="'+ i +'">'+ i +'</option>');                   
                }else{
                    $('#'+el.id+'yy')[0].options[ind].selected = false;
                };

            };
            ind ++;
        };      
    }
```

When I edit the date the `fieldChangeHandler` function calculates the selected date as `Sat Oct 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`. This is the correct date that I set in the form.

The custom `date` attribute on the selected element contains the column name:

```
event.srcElement.attributes["date"]
    date=​"CREATEDDATE"
```

So the form `fieldUpdate` function is called with the following parameters:

```
myForm.fieldUpdate(​"CREATEDDATE", "Oct 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)");
```

Once we have done the `fieldUpdate` the `updateFields` is called to refresh the screen, but now:

```
fields["CREATEDDATE"] = "2017-10-06T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Between setting the `CREATEDDATE` in the `fieldUpdate` function and the callback to `updateFields` we seem to have lost a day... (It was probably a Saturday!)

---

**Cut down example.**

I update the field with a new date:

```
function minimaltest()  {
    var dt = new Date(0);           
    myForm.fieldUpdate(
        "CREATEDDATE", 
        dt.setFullYear(2017, 0, 1)
    );
}
```

The server calls back to the `updatefields` function:

```
    function updateFields(result) {
        ...
    }
```

But the result does not contain the date I passed in...

```
result = Object {CUSTOMERS: Object}
CUSTOMERS:
Object
1:Object
CREATEDDATE:"2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Interestingly however, the same call with `dt.setFullYear(2017, 0, 20)` (20/01/17) returns an illegal date error, as if month and day components are being switched.

```
Object {
  "type": "error",
  "code": "stop",
  "message": "Illegal date.",
  "form": "Object",
  "fatal": false
}
```

Comment: You'd do much better to reduce your code to just sufficient to show the issue by creating a [*minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Much of your logic is tied up with jQuery and HTML so it's difficult to see what's going on. Post the example as a runnable snippet, the current code has errors. Where is the *focusdiv* function?

Comment: Fair comment. The full example is here: [link](https://erpdemo.emerge-it.co.uk/ui/index1.html). Use the Customer Number "T000043a". I'll add a cut down example to the question.

Comment: Could you try send the date to updateField in ISO format. `dt = new Date('01/20/2017'); dt.toISOString();`

Comment: if I do that `myForm.fieldUpdate(event.srcElement.attributes["date"].nodeValue, dt.toISOString);` the created date returned by `updateFields` is a zero length string.

Comment: Can u update the example link with the `toISOString` changes. I want to debug it and see what went wrong.

Comment: Updated, but I spotted this: dt = 
Thu Oct 05 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
dt.toISOString() = 
"2017-10-04T23:00:00.000Z"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue here was that the date that was being passed contained an offset for British Summer Time (/looks out window at rain. For a given value of "summer" I guess).

BST is 60 minutes behind the UTC timestamp Priority is expecting, so the date was passed was the date - 60 minutes, or 23:00 the day before the value we expected.

Rather than converting date+offset `toISOString`, we can create the UTC date (sans offset) using `Date(`[Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)`())` like so:

```
var dt = new Date(
    Date.UTC(
        $('#'+event.srcElement.attributes["date"].nodeValue+'yy')[0].value,
        $('#'+event.srcElement.attributes["date"].nodeValue+'mm')[0].value,
        $('#'+event.srcElement.attributes["date"].nodeValue+'dd')[0].value
    )
);
```

However, I'm still getting and `Illegal date` error when I specify and day > 12...

---

Update 2.

The illegal date was caused by using US English (3) in the config, rather than UK English (2). (Doh!)

```
var config = {
    url: 'https://erpdemo.emerge-it.co.uk',
    language: 2,
    ...
};
```